# zend studio xdebug profiling button is unclickable

Tags: xdebug

Windows+php+apache

debugging works except profiling. The "profile" btn. is clickable when choosing zend debugger as the debugger server but, turn gray and unclickable when choose xdebug. Does zend studio support xdebug profiling?

Answer (score 0):

ZendStudio does not support profiling with xdebug (only with ZendDebugger)

Comment: How about eclipse? I installed eclipse only to find no profiling function there.